# delete operator not deleting object property

Tags: javascript

I have a delete operator code snippet which is as following:

```js
(function() {
  var objA = Object.create({
    foo: 'foo'
  });
  var objB = objA;
  objB.foo = 'bar';

  delete objA.foo;
  console.log(objA.foo);
  console.log(objB.foo);
}());
```

```
//it logs-> foo
```

As the `delete` operator is used to delete `foo` property it shouldn't exist and thus `undefined` should be logged in console. However it is logging `foo` which is value of the property at the time of initialization. Why is it not deleting the property?

Comment: Use `Object.create(null, {foo:{value:'foo', configurable:true}});` to add properties to the new object rather than to its `[[Prototype]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check documentation of [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

> If a property with the same name exists on the object's prototype
>   chain, then, after deletion, the object will use the property from the
>   prototype chain (in other words, delete only has an effect on own
>   properties).

The method [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) create object with prototype properties

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified
>   prototype object and properties.

So `delete objA.foo;` does not delete proto property of object

Answer (score 8):

```
var objA = Object.create({
    foo: 'foo'
});
```

creates an object `objA` with `objA.__proto__` (its prototype) set to `{foo: 'foo'}`. There is no actual `objA.foo` property, it is actually `objA.__proto__.foo`, so nothing is deleted.

If you do instead

```
var objA = {foo: 'foo'}
```

then your code would work.

A demo:

```js
var refObj = {a: 'a'};
var proto = {
  foo: refObj
};
var objA = Object.create(proto);

console.log(objA.foo === objA.__proto__.foo) // should be true
delete objA.foo
console.log(objA.foo) // should print something
delete objA.__proto__.foo
console.log(objA.foo) // should be undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason behind this is that [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates an object, and the prototype of that object is specified by the parameter.

Here, you're setting the prototype of the `objA` as a regular JavaScript object with the property `foo`, and the same is referenced by `objB`.

`delete` only deletes the property owned by the object. Hence it isn't deleting the property `foo` as it is part of the prototype, not the object.

Finally, `console.log` logs the value of `foo` to the console due to the [prototype chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). JavaScript looks for a property in the chain until it is found or the root object is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the problem was is that the Object.create() method creates another object based off of a prototype, and it takes a second parameter that makes up the objects properties. So there is only a prototype created without any reference to the object being created by .create() method.

```
(function() {
    var objA = Object.create({}, 
       { "objA": { foo: 'foo' }
       } // Object with its property foo.
    );

    var objB = objA;
    objB.foo = 'bar';

    delete objA.foo;

    console.log(objA.foo);
    console.log(objB.foo);
 }());
```

I hope this helps you out! If you need me to elucidate, I can do so tomorrow.

Here is the Mozilla link, for further reading: [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  var objA = Object.create({
    foo: 'foo'
  }); //1
  var objB = objA //2
  //console.log(objA.hasOwnProperty("foo")) //returns false
  objB.foo = 'bar' //3
  //console.log(objA.hasOwnProperty("foo")) //returns true
  delete objA.foo //4
  console.log(objA.foo) //5
}());
```

**Output : foo foo**

1. In first step, we create an object using `Object.create()` method. `Object.create()` method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and the mentioned properties are inside prototype object, not in the object itself.
2. The property foo is not in `objA`, it is present inside the prototype of `objA`.
3. We assign the `objA` to `objB`, now both variables points to same object. And we create a new `foo` property in the object. This `foo` property is different from the `foo` property inside the prototype object.
4. When we delete the foo property in the `objA` we are just deleting the property we later added. The `foo` property inside prototype object is still available and takes over when the `foo` property is deleted from the object itself.